# Is there any differences between JsonObject (gson) and JSONObject (org.json)?

Tags: json, gson, org.json

I am new to Gson and what confuses me, specially when using `JsonElement.getAsJsonObject()`, is the type `JsonObject`.

Does it have any differences with `JSONObject`?

If it does, what are they?

And if it is the same, is there any reason why can't it be cast to `JSONObject`?

Comment: Other than they have nothing in common and are two completely different pieces of code? No.

Answer (score 1):

They are different classes from different packages from different sources ([Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is from Google, [`org.json`](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) is from Douglas Crockford), so no, you can't just cast one to the other. If you're using Gson, use Gson; if you're using `org.json`, use `org.json`.

Comment: OK. Thanks. But mainly I was wondering about their technical differences (if there's any) aside from being from two different developers.